# PHP Search SEO optimisation with url rewrite

Tags: php, forms, mod-rewrite

Hey guys can someone tell me how to make my search button with url rewrite because its not cool my whole site is with url rewrite and the search to be /Articles/Search/?s=......
Here is my form:

```
<form action="Articles/Search/" method="get">
<input type="text" value="Търси" name="s" id="keyword" title="s" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)" class="txt_field" />
<input type="submit" value="" id="searchbutton" title="Търси" class="sub_btn" /></form>
```

I want to like: /Articles/Search/keyword1-keyword2/
I can exchange the spaces.It would be nice if its without forward with php , maybe js

Comment: **how to make my search button with url rewrite** what does it exactly mean.

Comment: I have edited it when i saw it wasn't explained very well. /Articles/Search/Keywords-here/ @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie

Comment: What have you tried so far? I mean it seems you already have quite some sense what you would need to do, so don't stop yet. Show passion, turn your ideas into code!

Comment: Are you sure you want search result to be SEO optimized?

Comment: I have idea but i really suck with jquery.My idea is when he click the button to stop the form then rewrite the action and again form submitting

Comment: @Andrey: I gave you a different idea in the answer. Keep in mind that the search engine does not submit any forms, so using some javascript won't do any good.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way to keep the search form URI "SEO Optimized" is (albeit not like you outline in the first step) to switch from the `GET` method to the `POST` method:

```
<form action="Articles/Search/" method="post">
```

Next to that you can then provide your own set of URIs that will work with the search functionality of your site like with any other parameter you already provide via the URIs:

```
http://example.com/keywords/keyword1/keyword2/
```

The `keywords` controller then could fire up a search with all parameters space separated or similar. This depends a bit which kind of URL-rewriting you use. So you need to adopt that to your concrete needs, but it should be rather easy as you already have done that for the rest of your site.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this.

Comment: Well you can offer a permalink to the search result on the search result page offering a link to the said *keywords* controller. Also you can endcode their search values and offer a non-post URI containing the data inside the URI. E.g. with base64 and parse_str and http build query

Comment: @PhilRykoff: And what have a user's bookmark to do with SEO? Please elaborate.

Comment: @PhilRykoff: Then you must have misread my answer. Only the form is with method post. An additional controller is introduced to handle URIs containing the keywords inside. That controller can be used to offer search result contents based on keywords to robots - like with any other kind of data-base based output in relation to URI.

Comment: You are totally right, +1